# Trying to extend WP_Customize_Control gives not found error in sage theme

Tags: wordpress

Hey i am trying to extend WP_Customize_Control class, to add custom dropdown of posts in Customizer using sage theme. I even tried to add class in customize_register action hook, but still i get not found error:

Fatal error: Class 'Roots\Sage\Customizer\WP_Customize_Control' not found in /home/wpsitesb/sites/rex2/wp-content/themes/rex-etyhadar_v1/lib/customizer.php on line 36

My code :

```
add_action('customize_register',  __NAMESPACE__ . '\\customizer_register_callback');


function customizer_register_callback($wp_customize ) {

    class Post_Dropdown_Custom_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {

         // Dropdown code.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is not an answer actually, but I write here because for the length of it and code fomating.

The problem is (I think) is the namespace.

In your [customiser.php](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/lib/customizer.php) you are under `Roots\Sage\Customizer\` namespace.

When you want to create your class by extending the `WP_Customize_Control` then you should use the global namespace.

Add a `\` sign before `WP_Customize_Control`.

```
class Post_Dropdown_Custom_Control extends \WP_Customize_Control  {
   //....
}
```

Please try it, and tell me the result.

Answer (score 0):

Check your WordPress version. It should be >= 3.4

If it is, the reason could be namespace , use '\'

Comment: My wp version is > 3.4 it is 4.5.3

Comment: then it could be namespace , use '\'

Comment: yes using '\' solved the issue, thanks for your help.